# excel increment a value in column based on value in another column

Tags: excel

In an excel file, I have an amount column,say D4. For every 1000 increase in that column the value in the column say D5 shud increase by 1. How should the formula (in excel) should be given to do this.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple formula:

```
=INT(A1/1000)
```

Result:

[image]